# How to push data over reactive websocket with Spring in response to request?

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am getting started with reactive websockets using Spring Boot 2.1.3. I created a `WebSocketHandler` implementation like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

Flux<EfficiencyData> flux = service.subscribeToEfficiencyData(1);
    var publisher = flux.map( o -> {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }).map(session::textMessage)
      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    return session.send(publisher);
}
```

This works, if I connect, I get serialized `EfficiencyData` every second in my websocket client.

However, I want to react to a request coming from the websocket to tell the `service` for what id I want the data. I managed to get the request info like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

    return session.send(session.receive().map(webSocketMessage -> {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

        return session.textMessage("Subscribing with id " + id);
    }));
```

Now I have no clue how to combine these 2 implementations?

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

    return session.send(session.receive().map(webSocketMessage -> {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

        Flux<EfficiencyData> flux = service.subscribeToEfficiencyData(id);
        var publisher = flux.map( o -> {
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }).map(session::textMessage)
                            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        return publisher; //Does not compile
    }));
```

But that does not compile since `publisher` is a `Flux<WebSocketMessage>` and it should be a `Publisher<WebSocketMessage>`. How should this be handled?

EDIT:

Following the Javadoc example of `WebSocketHandler`, I tried this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    Flux<EfficiencyData> flux =
            session.receive()
                   .map(webSocketMessage -> Integer.parseInt(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText()))
                   .concatMap(service::subscribeToEfficiencyData);
    Mono<Void> input = flux.then();
    Mono<Void> output = session.send(flux.map(data -> session.textMessage(data.toString()))).then();
    return Mono.zip(input, output).then();
}
```

But that just disconnects the websocket client immediately without doing anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webflux websocketclient, How to send multiple requests in same session\[design client library\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812515/webflux-websocketclient-how-to-send-multiple-requests-in-same-sessiondesign-cl)

Comment: @OlehDokuka I saw that linked question before, but I fail to see how that helps here.

Comment: right. I see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `flatMap` or `concatMap` in order to flatten returned publisher

To fix your issue you have to use operators that allows flatting of the returned value. For example

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

    return session.send(
       session.receive()
              .flatMap(webSocketMessage -> {
                  int id = Integer.parseInt(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

                  Flux<EfficiencyData> flux = service.subscribeToEfficiencyData(id);
                  var publisher = flux
                      .<String>handle((o, sink) -> {
                         try {
                            sink.next(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o));
                         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return; // null is prohibited in reactive-streams
                         }
                      })
                      .map(session::textMessage)
                      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

                  return publisher;
              })
    );
}
```

## Key takeaways

1. If the return type is a stream, use `flatMap` or `concatMap` (see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571491/what-is-the-difference-between-concatmap-and-flatmap-in-rxjava/41988240)
2. Never returns `Null`. In reactive-streams `Null` is prohibited value (see specification rules [here](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#2.13)
3. When mapping can end up with `null` -> use `handle` operator. See more expalation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595420/correct-way-of-throwing-exceptions-with-reactor/53596358#53596358)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Would it be good to use `sink.error(e);` in the catch block?

Comment: How to I add the `session.textMessage("Subscribing with id " + id);` upon websocket connection?

Comment: Do you want to send it prior any messages?

Comment: `> Thank you so much for this. Would it be good to use sink.error(e); in the catch block?`

If you want to close connection ->, then it would be. otherwise, it makes sense to convert it to some specific user-readable message and send it over the WS connection

Comment: Do you want to send it prior any messages? -> Does it make a difference?

Comment: Anyway, you can do that like that -> `session.receive().startsWith(Flux.just(session.textMessage("Subscribing with id " + id)))....`

Comment: im getting response like this {
  "scanAvailable": true,
  "prefetch": -1
}