# what is the difference between RSocket and Spring webflux websocket?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, rsocket, spring-rsocket

What is the difference between Spring webflux WebSocket and RSocket? I am trying to implement reactive websocket in my spring boot project but I see RSocket under a separate section on the spring webflux website along with spring websocket.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#rsocket

Difference between webflux websocket and rsockect?

Answer (score 0):

Oleh Dokuka has already written a long detailed answer, that covers everything. I think from that answer you will get an overview, of why to use RSocket.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926639/15647017